# How to signup for Online 30 day free trail - dynamics crm 2011 version

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I am new to Microsoft Dynamics CRM,  I am trying to sign up for 30 day free trail Microsoft Dynamics 2011 version online, but by default I can see 2013 version, can someone please help on how to change to 2011. I am really sorry if this sounds silly, just want to know if there is any option.

Comment: Why? If you want to try out different things and you are already using CRM 2011 as you say, then just set up a test organization in your current deployment, or install a new instance of CRM 2011 using a trial licence for CRM, SQL etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you signup for a trial or buy a new istance, Dynamics CRM Online offers always the latest version available for the selected area (US, EMEA, APAC). Currently is CRM 2013, this means you can't get a CRM 2011 Online trial.

Comment: Thank you. my company currently uses 2011 version, so want to make sure if there is any possibility to get 2011.